# using 'es' for subjective masculine pronoun

Tags: pronoun, personal-pronoun

A : Ist dein Tisch neu?
B :
   (1) Ja, er ist neu.
    (2) Ja, es ist neu.
    (3) Ja, der ist neu.

Tisch is masculine. So I know B-(1) is correct. But can we say B-(2) also? I think 'es' is for neutral nouns so it is wrong to use 'es' here. and I understand B-(3) is also correct.
Please a native German speaker check if my understanding is correct. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, (1) and (3) are correct and (2) is wrong.

Comment: (2) is wrong and (1) and (3) are correct. You should use _es_ only for neuter nouns. Neuter pronouns are not a wildcard for all genders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun *der Tisch* is masculine. So only masculine pronouns can refer to it.

- er
  **masculine** personal pronoun
- es
  **neuter** personal pronoun
- der
  **masculine** demonstrative pronoun

This means:

> Ja, er ist neu. = richtig
>   Ja, es ist neu. = falsch
>   Ja, der ist neu. = richtig

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have posted another question. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/when-to-use-es-as-pronoun